# Возвращение VARIANT

Tags: c++, com

Пишу реализацию COM-сервера. Один из методов должен возвращать VARIANT. В idl у меня такое объявление

```
HRESULT _stdcall Method([out, retval] VARIANT * res);
```

из него получается такой h файл

```
STDMETHOD(Method)(VARIANT * res);
```

Вопрос: как мне правильно возвратить результат? Должен ли я в методе вызвать `VariantInit(res)`? Или это делает вызывающая сторона? Если должен, то должен ли я предварительно вызвать `VariantClear(res)`? Или я всегда получаю указатель на неинициализированный VARIANT?

Или у меня должен быть такой код?

```cpp
if (res->vt != VT_EMPTY)
    VariantClear(res);
VariantInit(res);
```

Этот VARIANT потом должен будет отмаршалиться в другой процесс.

Comment: Ну вообще можно сделать по-разному, но если сам метод никогда не должен использовать входное значение, то имеет смысл сделать его выходным параметром, например по образцу `IPropertyStore::GetValue`. Это подразумевает, что всегда передается указатель именно на неинициализированный объект, который оказывается инициализированным только если функция завершается успешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатель `res` не может содержать указатель на мусорную память, поэтому в функции мы вызываем `VariantClear(res)` который, при необходимости, очистит содержимое res (уменьшит счетчики ссылок) и установит `vt = VT_EMPTY`, а потом с этим указателем работаем как нам нужно.

Второй способ: работаем с классом `ATL::CComVariant`, а в конце вызываем метод `Detach(res)`. Он тоже внутри вызовет `VariantClear(res)`, скопирует в res структуру `tagVARIANT` и откажется от своих прав на нее